# PHP not debugging/showing error messages

Tags: lighttpd, php5, error-handling

I've just installed lighttpd, and I'm not seeing any error messages on pages when I know errors must have occurred. All I get is a blank page. However, I do get the errors in the error log file - but I really want to see them while I develop instead of going into the log.

Surely lighttpd isn't supposed to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your php.ini, make sure you have:

```
display_errors = On
```

Comment: Sure, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You might need to tweak your php.ini file.

The values you probably want to change are these:
`error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`
`display_errors = On`
`display_startup_errors = On`

It's not recommended to set these values on a production server, just dev machines.

If lighthttpd is like Apache, you'll also need to restart the service to pick up the new config changes.